# Creating a Wildcard DNS Record

Tags: domain-name-system

What does '@' means and how is it different from '*'?

I want to set *.myhost.com to resolve to IP x.x.x.x.  So, I am creating a DNS type A record pointing to the IP.  I don't want to have to create an entry for each of my sub-domains.

Comment: Um. There's no question here. What you've said is correct, you want to make a wildcard A record for `*` in your domain.com zone. This is valid and correct if you choose to implement that way.

Comment: Funny that some people responded and got Ups, right?

Comment: Yup, they got Ups because they put in more effort than you did.

Comment: Wow.  I've got to start looking at dates more closely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@ refers to the current ORIGIN in your zone file, usually the domain in question.

If you did

```
@ IN A 172.31.31.31
```

in the mydomain.com zomefile, it would make `mydomain.com` resolve to `172.31.31.31`.

If you did

```
* IN A 172.31.31.31
```

then **all** hostnames would resolve to `172.31.31.31`

Answer (score 0):

Also it must be said, that you can read about these DNS things in "DNS and BIND" book, and in most any manual, where DNS zone syntax are describes.

Comment: Most of the questions on this site can be answered by reading the documentation.  That isn't the purpose of this community.  I'm not going to downvote this answer, but I'd reconsider posting unhelpful answers like this.